# Batches with BulkWriter in google firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Does anyone know why this does not work, what am I doing wrong here. It get stuck after the console.log "after read stream"

I am trying to read a bunch of files, convert it to json and upload with bulkwriter to firestore.
After each 400 document I am calling `close` to write them to firestore and then I am creating a new bulkwriter

I also tried awaiting `bulkWriter.create(eventDoc, {})` but it does not work. It also get stuck and there is no error. Why is this ? the create method returns a promise.
Why can't it be awaited ?
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/BulkWriter.html#create

The idea is to process 1 file at the time and it can contains tens of thousands of rows which needs to be uploaded to firestore

I am calling this method in `for...of` loop and awaiting the `processBatch` method

Any help highly appreciated

```js
async processBatch(document: string, file: string): Promise<void> {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    console.log('start: ', document);
    let bulkWriter;
    const writeBatchLimit = 400;
    let documentsInBatch = 0;
    let totalInDocument = 0;
    const eventsCollectionRef = db.collection('events');
    const eventDoc = eventsCollectionRef.doc(document);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('promise');
        bulkWriter = db.bulkWriter();
        const csvStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
        console.log('after read stream');
        bulkWriter.create(eventDoc, {})
            .then(result => {
                console.log('Successfully: ', result);
                csvStream.pipe(csvParser())
                    .on('data', row => {
                        console.log('row');
                        bulkWriter.create(eventDoc.collection('event').doc(), row);
                        documentsInBatch++;
                        if (documentsInBatch > writeBatchLimit) {
                            bulkWriter.close();
                            totalInDocument = + documentsInBatch;
                            documentsInBatch = 0;
                            bulkWriter = db.bulkWriter();
                        }
                    })
                    .on('end', () => {
                        console.log('file: ', file + ', totalInDocument: ', totalInDocument);
                        resolve();
                    });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('Failed: ', err);
                reject();
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```js
async processBatch(document: string, file: string): Promise<void> {
        const db = admin.firestore();
        console.log(`start: ${document}`);
        let bulkWriter;
        const writeBatchLimit = 400;
        let documentsInBatch = 0;
        let numOfBatches = 0;
        let totalInDocument = 0;
        const eventsCollectionRef = db.collection('events');
        const eventDoc = eventsCollectionRef.doc(document);
        bulkWriter = db.bulkWriter();
        const csvStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
        bulkWriter.create(eventDoc, {});
        csvStream.pipe(csvParser())
            .on('data', row => {
                bulkWriter.create(eventDoc.collection('event').doc(), row);
                documentsInBatch++;
                if (documentsInBatch > writeBatchLimit) {
                    numOfBatches++;
                    totalInDocument += documentsInBatch;
                    documentsInBatch = 0;
                    bulkWriter.close();
                    console.log(`Committing batch ${numOfBatches}, cumulative: ${totalInDocument}`);
                    bulkWriter = db.bulkWriter();
                }
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log(`file: ${file}, totalInDocument: ${totalInDocument}`);
            });
    }
```